how to change background for each called month in calendar
i'm using the semantic calendar from https://fullcalendar.io and i am trying to have the background for each month change.  i have not been able to find how to do this as the code looks like it calls them up via math calculations.  is there a way to add javascript to look for the info in the h2 code and compare it, if it's january XXXX then background is background.png?
here is the calendar being called in html, as you cann see it;s just calling the js function so i cant alter anything here
 <div id='calendar' style="background-image: url('assets/images/pgs/month01.png'); background-size: 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat; width: 81.5%;  z-index: 8; position:relative; float: right;"></div>

this is the code on the page inspect after it's run:
<h2 class="fc-toolbar-title" id="fc-dom-1">January 2024</h2>

maybe the js is editable but i think it's best to just add a new script on the html page that reads the info ad changes it that way?
i think this is part of the js that calls the month:
function Tl(e,t){for(let n in e)console.warn(Unknown option '${n}'+(t? for view '${t}':""))}class _l extends Xn{render(){return g("div",{className:"fc-toolbar-chunk"},...this.props.widgetGroups.map(e=>this.renderWidgetGroup(e)))}renderWidgetGroup(e){let{props:t}=this,{theme:n}=this.context,r=[],i=!0;for(let s of e){let{buttonName:e,buttonClick:o,buttonText:l,buttonIcon:a,buttonHint:c}=s;if("title"===e)i=!1,r.push(g("h2",{className:"fc-toolbar-title",id:t.titleId},t.title));else{let i=e===t.activeButton,s=!t.isTodayEnabled&&"today"===e||!t.isPrevEnabled&&"prev"===e||!t.isNextEnabled&&"next"===e,d=[fc-${e}-button,n.getClass("button")];i&&d.push(n.getClass("buttonActive")),r.push(g("button",{type:"button",title:"function"==typeof c?c(t.navUnit):c,disabled:s,"aria-pressed":i,className:d.join(" "),onClick:o},l||(a?g("span",{className:a,role:"img"}):"")))}}if(r.length>1){return g("div",{className:i&&n.getClass("buttonGroup")||""},...r)}return r[0]}}

so if anyone can help, i'm drawing a blank on how to call the function to look at the title and then change the background for it. maybe an array would work?  i'm just lost atm, any help would be great.

Are you sure you want to use a 3rd party calendar at this point? HTML 5 includes calendar and time fields through input type=... making 3rd party calendars redundant. All the time you use in doing what you say you want to do here is going to add to code maintenance over time... until you eventually switch to the standard. In the business world programmers can be prone to wanting to make something cool rather than something maintainable that better fits business needs, which it seems like you are doing here

I updated my answer to use the a cleaner code than what you posted in your other question

This should work with a Mutation Observer. You can watch for changes to the DOM tree inside the div with the calendar. After a change you can extract the Headline and call a function to apply a style to the div. I only changed the bg color, but putting in an image follows the same principle.


// Select the node that will be observed for mutations
const calendarDivNode = document.getElementById("calendar");

// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
const config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
const callback = (mutationList, observer) => {
  let monthFromElement = document.getElementById("fc-dom-1").innerHTML;
  let month = monthFromElement.replace(/[0-9]/g, "").trim();
  changeBackground(month);
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(calendarDivNode, config);

// Function to change background
function changeBackground(month) {
  const colors = {December: "red", January: "blue", February: "cyan"}; // extend the object to cover every month, for images provide urls instead of colors
  calendarDivNode.style.backgroundColor = colors[month];
}



I tried this solution in this codepen.

this is wonderful, the background colors works perfectly but for the life of me i cant get the images to work.  i am clearly doing something wrong

function changeBackground(month) {
const colors = {December: "element.style.backgroundImage = "url('assets/images/pgs/month01.png')"; element.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat"; element.style.backgroundPosition = "center";", January: "blue", February: "cyan"}; // extend the object to cover every month, for images provide urls instead of colors
calendarDivNode.style.backgroundColor = colors[month];
}

nevermind, i figured out what i was doing wrong. thank you so much!!!!

Here is a way
You could consider using a mutation observer
Improving your version of the mutation observer to change the outer div


const config = {
    attributes: true,
    childList: true,
    subtree: true
  },
  colors = {
    January: "url('https://placehold.co/600x400/blue/white')",
    February: "url('https://placehold.co/600x400/pink/white')",
    March: "url('https://placehold.co/600x400/green/yellow')",
    April: "url('https://placehold.co/600x400/pastelgreen/white')",
    May: "url('https://placehold.co/600x400/lightblue/white')",
    June: "url('https://placehold.co/600x400/yellow/orange')",
    July: "url('https://placehold.co/600x400/red/yellow')",
    August: "url('https://placehold.co/600x400/orange/blue')",
    September: "url('https://placehold.co/600x400/teal/white')",
    October: "url('https://placehold.co/600x400/orange/black')",
    November: "url('https://placehold.co/600x400/brown/white')",
    December: "url('https://placehold.co/600x400/red/green')"
  };

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
  const calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth'
  });
  calendar.render();

//  const calendarDivNode = document.getElementById("calendar");
  const calendarDivNode = document.querySelector(".bgcontainer");
  const changeBackground = month => {
    Object.assign(calendarDivNode.style, {
      backgroundImage: colors[month],
      backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
      backgroundSize: "100%",
      backgroundPosition: "right"
    });
  };
  const callback = () => {
    const monthFromElement = document.getElementById("fc-dom-1").innerHTML;
    const month = monthFromElement.replace(/[0-9]/g, "").trim();
    changeBackground(month);
  };
  const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
  observer.observe(calendarDivNode, config);
  const currentMonth = new Date().toLocaleString('default', {
    month: 'long'
  });
  changeBackground(currentMonth);
});
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@6.1.15/index.global.min.js'></script>

<!-- div bg container for calendar -->

<div class="bgcontainer">


  <div id='calendar'></div>

  <!-- end of div bg container for calendar -->


</div>



Here is a colour change of the calendar only


const months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth'
  });
  calendar.render();

  setInterval(() => {
    const currentMonth = document.getElementById('fc-dom-1').textContent.split(' ')[0];
    months.forEach(month => calendarEl.classList.toggle(month, month === currentMonth));
  }, 100);
});
.January {
  background-color: teal;
  color: white;
}

.February {
  background-color: pink;
  color: white;
}

.March {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  color: yellow;
}

.April {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

.May {
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: white;
}

.June {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: orange;
}

.July {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.August {
  background-color: orange;
  color: blue;
}

.September {
  background-color: teal;
  color: white;
}

.October {
  background-color: orange;
  color: black;
}

.November {
  background-color: brown;
  color: white;
}

.December {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@6.1.15/index.global.min.js'></script>

<div id='calendar'></div>



